# building an arbitarily deep nested Python dict without checking for key existence along the way

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, associative-array

In bash I can use `mkdir`'s `-p` flag to create a directory that is several directories deep without having to check for the existence of all of its ancestor directories, and create them if needed; it will create any nonexistent parent directories along the way. `rm -rf a; mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f` will create `a`, and then `b` inside it, and then `c` inside `b`, and so on, all the way to `f`.

In Python I want to be able to do something similar with dictionaries:

```py
nested_dict = dict()
nested_dict["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"] = "f"
```

`collections.defaultdict` will give me one level of 'forgiveness' if a key does not exist (e.g. `if not "a" in nested_dict.keys(): nested_dict["a"]["b"] = "something"` will not raise an Exception if nested_dict is a defaultdict(dict) but not an arbitrarily deep level. Is there currently a nice way of doing such a thing in Python?

Comment: Use the `infinity_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(infinity_dict)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a `lambda` that gives a new `defaultdict` in the constructor.

```
create_dict = lambda : nested_dict
nested_dict = default_dict(create_dict)
```